# ZingChart does not display all the words in wordcloud

Tags: javascript, charts, zingchart

I am using wordcloud where I am just passing a set of words which I want to be displayed in word cloud without being ignored. For example,
"text" : "you are a good person" All words like "you"," are","a","good","person". How can I do this?? Where is all the documentation for this available??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

full disclosure I'm a member of the ZingChart team.

There is an attribute called `min-length` that has a default value of 2. You can set the value to 1 or 0. We have some cool examples in our [gallery](https://www.zingchart.com/gallery/#WordCloud). We also have wordcloud documentation [here](https://www.zingchart.com/docs/chart-types/wordcloud/).

```js
var myConfig = {
    "graphset":[
        {
            "type":"wordcloud",
            "options":{
                "text":"you are a gg good person",
                "max-items":200,
                "min-length":1
            }
       }
    ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id : 'myChart', 
 data : myConfig, 
 height: "100%", 
 width: "100%"
});
```

```css
html,body,#myChart{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <!--Assets will be injected here on compile. Use the assets button above-->
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
  <script> zingchart.MODULESDIR = "https://cdn.zingchart.com/modules/";
</script>
 <!--Inject End-->
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id='myChart'></div>
 </body>
</html>
```